Where can I ask this question about managing Git servers?
I have the following question that I've already attempted to ask on Software Engineering SE and Stack Overflow, but both were closed. Where can I ask this question?

I'm planning to manage a cluster of Git servers. There are a few requirements for the functional requirements:

Users should not be concerned with the fact that there are a cluster of Git servers. Ultimately, they just need to run the commands "git
push" and "git fetch" and get their feature development going.

Repos should be replicated across multiple Git servers. If a git server is down, another Git server that stores the replica can serve
the repo. When users push changes, they will automatically connect to
that new Git server.

Ideally, clusters should ensure the load of Git servers are balanced. This means it's unlikely that a server needs to handle 1000
users and another server is almost idle.


I'm planning to deploy the Git servers on AWS EC2. For now, I don't
have any clues how to make these "stateful" Git servers reliable.


An attempt was made here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/454099/how-to-scale-git-servers-reliably

I don't see a question in the quoted text

@mutu I think the question is "how can I make these "stateful" Git servers reliable?". But then we need a definition of what 'reliable' means in this context.
